# Display none adds a new line in jQuery button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

In jQuery, I am having a button(toggle) to set display none/block. When i click on the button it adds a new line.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="tdDisplay">Click me!</button>
    <table>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top">
            <td>
                <label style="font-weight: normal">Placement Preference :</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio"  id="rbOrderByActivityGroup" class='rbImgChecker'  name="rbPlacement" style="margin-right: 5px;float:left" />Order by Batch -  Reverse order after each activity batch<br />
                <img id="ImgOByActivityGroup"  class='rbImgChecker' src="Images/orderByActivityBatch.png" /><br />

                <input type="radio"   id="rbOBSReverse" class='rbImgChecker' name="rbPlacement" style="margin-right: 5px;float:left" />Order by Subject - Reverse order after each activity<br />
                <img id="ImgOBSReverse"  class='rbImgChecker' src="Images/orderBySubjectReverse.png" /><br />

                <input type="radio"   id="rbOBS" class='rbImgChecker' name="rbPlacement" style="margin-right: 5px;float:left" />Order by Subject<br />
                <img id="ImgOBS"  class='rbImgChecker' src="Images/orderBySubject.png" /><br />

                <input type="radio"   id="rbOBA" class='rbImgChecker' name="rbPlacement" style="margin-right: 5px;float:left" />Order by Activity<br />
                <img id="ImgOBA"  class='rbImgChecker' src="Images/orderByActivity.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**script:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var checker = true;
        if(checker)
            $('#tdDisplay').click(function () {
                if (checker)
                    $(".rbImgChecker").css("display", "block");
                else
                    $(".rbImgChecker").css("display", "none");
                checker = !checker;
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The default (computed) `display` value for `img` is `inline`, not `block`. Since this is jQuery, why not use `.show()` and `.hide()` or even `.toggle()` instead, and avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: try `display:inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: you got a jsFiddle for that?

Comment: But what is the problem with display:block.why it creates a new line?

Comment: 'Block' creates a new line that is it's behaviour http://learnlayout.com/display.html read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
$('#tdDisplay').click(function () {                    
    $(".rbImgChecker").toggle();                  
});
```

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will set `display` to either `inline` or `none`according to its actual state.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fj5auanh/)**